# The valid value for MobileDeviceAction in directory API

Tags: google-directory-api

What are the valid values for MobileDeviceAction? I want to wipe a mobile device remotely. However, the "wipe" is not a valid value for the directory API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/mobiledevices/action). The API always returns the error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value for: wipe is not a valid value",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid value for: wipe is not a valid value",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you figured this out? The Google documentation is infuriating, I can't find valid values anywhere. ChromeOS actions on the other hand have that listed.

Comment: Not yet, I still could not figure the valid value.

Comment: The only value I've been able to find that works is "approve", but this is the opposite of what I'm trying to do (wipe account).

Comment: Google provided a new API(https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/devices/wipe). The mobiledevices API method are going to deprecated. We have implemented this new API. However, some mobile devices could not be wiped. The identity API returns "Internal error encountered. [500]"

Comment: I posted an answer with the accepted values. It sounds like the action you were looking for is "admin_remote_wipe"

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully Google with update their documentation, but in the meantime this might help someone avoid the massive frustration I went through. The accepted values for MobileDeviceAction are the following:

- "admin_remote_wipe"
- "admin_account_wipe"
- "approve"
- "block"
- "cancel_remote_wipe_then_activate"
- "cancel_remote_wipe_then_block"
- "disable"

Comment: Awesome! Some devices could not be wiped by this API. We have posted these devices information to Google.

Comment: Finally, we use the directory API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/mobiledevices/action) with these provided values. Specifically, this API needs the resource id of devices. These devices that could not be wiped before are wiped successfully by this API.